# Subconsultas e média no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Dadas 3 tabelas de uma database que simula um senso de municípios brasileiros:

````
CREATE TABLE municipio (cod_mun char (7), nome varchar(50), cod_uf(2), CONSTRAINT municipio_pk PRIMARY KEY (cod_mun), CONSTRAINT cod_uf_fk FOREIGN KEY (cod_uf) REFERENCES uf (cod_uf));

CREATE TABLE senso (ano int(4), cod_mun char(7), pib decimal(12,3), populacao (11), CONSTRAINT senso_pk PRIMARY KEY (ano, cod_mun), CONSTRAINT cod_mun_fk FOREIGN KEY (cod_mun) REFERENCES municipio (cod_mun));```

Tem-se a seguinte pergunta:
Quais são as cidades do estado da Bahia cuja população é maior que a média do estado em cada ano?

Eu consegui selecionar a média do estado da Bahia por ano com a seguinte query:

```SELECT AVG(populacao), ano FROM senso WHERE cod_mun IN (SELECT cod_mun FROM municipio WHERE cod_uf IN (SELECT cod_uf FROM uf WHERE estado = 'Bahia')) GROUP BY ano;```

Entretanto, a partir daqui não sei como faço para selecionar as cidades bahianas que possuem populações maiores do que a média do estado nos respectivos anos de senso.
````

Comment: Estude a cláusula `HAVING` e também junções, em particular `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT m.nome, s.ano
FROM municipio as m
LEFT JOIN senso as s ON s.cod_mun = m.cod_mun
WHERE  s.populacao > (SELECT AVG(populacao) FROM senso WHERE ano = s.ano) as media_populacao
GROUP BY s.ano, m.nome
ORDER BY s.ano DESC, m.nome ASC